# What are NInject's assumptions about GetHashCode?

Tags: ninject

Ninject uses an `ActivationCacheStrategy` strategy, which simply stores the object in a hash map. This means that the GetHashCode method of the object must be available. I have a situation similar to the following:

```
var something = kernel.Get<ISomething>();
something.Load() {
```

which does something like:

```
var objectA = kernel.Get<IFoobar>();
objectA.Init(...);

var objectB = kernel.Get<IFoobar>();
objectB.Init(...)
```

etc.

The problem is that the GetHashCode of objectA is not available until Init is called. It seems  that Ninject assumes GetHashCode is available before the object is fully activated.

My question is if this behaviour is intended, and if so, what the intended solution is to this. I could of course add a non-caching activation cache of sorts to my kernel (removing the default), but this feels wrong.

Comment: When I understand correctly you have an issue in your GetHashCode implementation. It does not follow the framework guidelines. See: The hash function must return exactly the same value regardless of any changes that are made to the object. That isn't an issue of ninject

Comment: I have to implement my GetHashCode using *some* information I obtain through construction/activation, after which, as you mention, it should remain constant. But Ninject has support for initialization methods (and other methods of activation), I find that I should be able to assume that my hashcode only needs to be constant/available *after* initialization, but perhaps this is not an assumption made by Ninject (?).